# Saving XML-File without converting & into & amp;

Tags: c#, xml

I have a data source from which my program creates a well-formed XML-file which should be used later in a xsl-file.

The data-source contains latex special chars.
I'm mapping them and creating local Entites.

An example.

xml data:

```
<!DOCTYPE my_entities[...<!ENTITY e228 "&#228;">]...>
  <inproceedings id="Abadie:94">
    <author>B. Abadie</author>
    <title>{''Vector bundles'' over quantum Heisenberg manifolds}</title>
    <booktitle>Algebraic Methods in Operator Theory</booktitle>
    <editor>R. Curto and P. E. T. J&amp;e248;rgensen</editor>
    <publisher>Birkh&amp;e228;user, Boston - Basel - Berlin</publisher>
    <year>1994</year>
  </inproceedings>
```

The line `<publisher>Birkh&amp;e228;user, Boston - Basel - Berlin</publisher>` should be `<publisher>Birkh&e228;user, Boston - Basel - Berlin</publisher>`. So the program converts the & into `&amp;`.

Im writing in C# and using the XmlDocument to write the xml-file.

How can I prevent the program to convert the & into an `&amp;`?

Kind Regards
Mario

Edit: I tried much with converting the `&amp;` within the xsl, but nothing worked well.

Comment: Show us your code.  Why don't you insert the characters directly?  There is no need to create custom entities.

Comment: The problem is the same.
The programm always saves `&amp;code;`

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that at all.  Just put `ä` in your source.

Comment: Sorry it must be the code in the first hand. Professors order : (
See code below.

Comment: Try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createentityreference(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

First I inserted the entities directly with their decimal code, than I tried it with the local own ones. The result was the same. I got `&amp;code;` than `&code;`

```
static void Create_Filled_XML() {
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.XmlResolver = null;

    try {
        string docType = "";
        foreach(KeyValuePair<string, DocEntity> pair in CommandMapper.SymbolMap)
                docType += pair.Value.GetEntityString();

        XmlDeclaration dec = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
        XmlDocumentType myDocType = doc.CreateDocumentType("my_entities", null, null, docType);
        XmlProcessingInstruction xslStyle = doc.CreateProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"03_bibtex.xsl\"");

        XmlNode root = doc.CreateElement("bibtext");

        foreach(BibElement bib in bibtex) {
            root.AppendChild(bib.GetXml(doc));
        }

        doc.AppendChild(dec);
        doc.AppendChild(myDocType);
        doc.AppendChild(xslStyle);
        doc.AppendChild(root);

        doc.Save(@"...\file.xml");
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```